# AngularJS: how to call a function whenever the slider button is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS, so any help I can get is very much appreciated!

So I have a slider that goes from 2-6. The numbers indicate hours.

What I would like to do is instead of having the click directive to calculate the time * cost whenever clicked, I would like to have a 2-way data binding occurring with the html and js. So when I move the slider one notch, it would recalculate the price and display it in html.

What I have so far is this:

```
<body ng-controller="pricingCtrl">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;" id="slider"></div>
    <div class="minumum-statement">*minimum 2 hours</div>
    <div class="hour-slider">
        <div class="slider-label">
            <div class="slider-hour2">2</div>
            <div class="slider-hour3">3</div>
            <div class="slider-hour4">4</div>
            <div class="slider-hour5">5</div>
            <div class="slider-hour6">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="calculate-button-container">
            <div ng-click="calculatePrice()" class="calculate-button"> Calculate </div>
    </div>

<div class="final-price-container">
        <div>
             <div  class="final-price">$ {{price}}</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('pricingApp', []);

app.controller('pricingCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [16],
        range: {
            'min': [  0 ],
            'max': [ 100 ]
        },
        step: 16
    });

    $scope.inputData = {};
    $scope.inputData.numAdults = '1';
    $scope.inputData.numChildren = '1';
    $scope.price = 60;

    $scope.calculatePrice = function () {
        var sliderValue = slider.noUiSlider.get();
        var numHours = (sliderValue / 16) + 1;
        if (numHours > 6) {
            numHours = 'All Day';
        }
        if (Number($scope.inputData.numAdults) + Number($scope.inputData.numChildren) === 1) {
            $scope.price = 25 * numHours;
        }
        else {
            $scope.price = (15 * (Number($scope.inputData.numAdults) + Number($scope.inputData.numChildren))) * numHours;
        }
        $scope.priceData = {
            numAdults: $scope.inputData.numAdults,
            numChildren: $scope.inputData.numChildren,
            price: $scope.price,
            totalNumPeople: Number($scope.inputData.numChildren) + Number($scope.inputData.numAdults),
            numHours: numHours
        };
    }

});
```

I was thinking using ng-watch to watch the value of the sliderValue in the js file. If it changes, then it recalculates price and then displays it back to the html using the expression.

Comment: A quick Google for "noUiSlider events" returned https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/.
Try adding `slider.noUiSlider.on('slide', $scope.calculatePrice);` to the controller.